# How to right-align text with the Vg library in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, vector-graphics

I would like to right-align text, i.e. draw text horizontally such that the rightmost x coordinate of the last character is where I specify.

I noticed a couple of things:

- Perhaps it would be useful to have a function that returns the coordinates of the smallest rectangular box that contains a path.
- Text is cut directly using `Vg.I.cut_glyphs` and there doesn't seem to be a way to obtain an explicit path for it, of type `Vg.P.t`.

Comment: Theoretically, you can reverse the text and use advances to layout text from right-to-left. In practice, a quick grep revealed that `glyphs` and `advances` are ignored by some backend (e.g., `html` , `svg`, and `cairo` - all use the `text` property directly), so it would probably work as expected only with the `pdf`backend. And probably you should raise this question in Discuss, where Daniel could be seen more often, so that you can get a more authorative answer :)

Comment: He replied on Github directly where I posted a link to this. I'm trying to avoid placing pressure on authors for simple user questions.